# Thunderbird 3.0 refuses to start on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, thunderbird

I just downloaded Thunderbird 3.0 on my Macbook Pro running Leopard, and installed it in `/Applications`. When I attempt to start it, the icon opens on the Dock as normal, but I get the following dialog.

[image: Close Thunderbird]

I don't have a `~/Library/Application Support/Thunderbird` directory at all, let alone a .parentlock file. While I didn't expect it to help, I did reboot my system. And sign out and back in. And close all programs besides Thunderbird.

Earlier versions of Thunderbird have worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird can create Profiles (and subsequently `.parentlock` files) at `~/Library/Application Support/Thunderbird/` and `~/Library/Thunderbird/`. The newer versions are supposed to put it in Application Support but I've seen instances where that is not the case.

Alternatively running `find ~ -name ".parentlock"` from the command line may help find the file (as the GUI/Spotlight won't show the file by default).

Comment: Right. Those directories don't exist because Thunderbird hasn't actually started yet.

Comment: So `find ~ -name ".parentlock"` revealed no .parentlock folders anywhere in your home folder?

Comment: No. But it started just fine the other day, though I'm sticking with Mail.app.